# Drop NaN containing rows in pandas DataFrame with column condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with Columns A,B,D and C. I would like to drop all NaN containing rows in the dataframe only where D and C columns contain value 0.

Eg:
[image]

Would anyone be able to help me in this issue.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
np.random.seed(2021)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,0,np.nan], size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df)
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  NaN  0.0  1.0
6  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
7  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
8  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
9  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If need remove columns if both `D` and `C` has `0` and another columns has `NaN`s use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if both values are `0` and chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` with
[`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one value is `NaN` tested by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
m = df[['D','C']].eq(0).all(axis=1) & df.isna().any(axis=1)

df1 = df[~m]
print (df1)
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
5  0.0  NaN  0.0  1.0
6  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
7  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
8  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
9  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Another alternative without `~` for invert, but all conditions and also `&` is changed to `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m = df[['D','C']].ne(0).any(axis=1) | df.notna().all(axis=1)

df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
5  0.0  NaN  0.0  1.0
6  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
7  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
8  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
9  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks